# How to receive and parse a JSON object from a HTTP POST request from client using java on the server side

Tags: java, json, http, post, windows-server-2019

I am working on an iOS app and the server-side needs to receive POST from the client. The client-side is programmed in swift and HTTP requests are sent using the **Alamofire** library. The connection is clear and `status code 200` is returned automatically by the server each time a POST request is sent. The content of the POST request is also correct. But how do I receive and parse the JSON object sent from the POST request by the client on the server-side? Certain actions on the server need the data from the POST requests.

The server side is written in Java, and I am using windows server 2019 on an **Amazon EC2 server**. Some clear directions would be great!

Comment: The problem is solved using InputStreamReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java application, I suggest u First use spring initialization to create a maven and spring boot project , with spring mvc framework in it.
Second write a spring mvc controller with post method, which serve the request from IOS. This is am example:

```
    @PostMapping("/xxx")
    public XXX addXXX(@Valid @RequestBody XXXAddForm xxxAddForm) {
        return xxxService.addXXX(xxxAddForm);
    }

    // this is the json object, which matches the format of your client side 
    public class XXXAddForm {
    }
```

Comment: I didn't really success by doing it this way, but it is solved using InputStreamReader. Thanks anyway :)